# Pardot Email Marketing Database with SurveyMonkey?

Tags: html, surveymonkey

Our organizations uses Pardot email automation platform that also works with our CRM Salesforce. Is there a way to tie in SurveyMonkey with our database to send an email that includes the survey on the eblast?

Thanks,
Kaitlin Bowes

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

While Pardot does not currently have a connector for SurveyMonkey, it has been suggested on the [ideas board](http://ideas.pardot.com/forums/36996-ideas/suggestions/3510503-integrate-with-surveymonkey-surveygizmo-for-survey). It wouldn't be a bad idea to mention this on there as well so it can be seen by the team.

Embedding a survey into an email is a little more than tricky. SurveyMonkey has [touched on the concept and issued this response](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Can-I-embed-the-survey-inside-an-email):

> The surveys are currently too complicated to render correctly in an HTML email. We may decide to add this in the future. In the meantime, you will need to create a Collector under the Collect tab and choose which type to use.